# Can not connect to Genymotion ADB

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I have 2 machines in the virtual box :
Santoku(linux) and device from Genymotion emulator

I want to connect to Genymotion ADB from another machine which is Santoku(linux) in the virtual box.

I made a network in Santoku Machine **Bridged** but when I make Network in Genymotion in the virtual box as **Bridged**, it is not working and give me this error:

[image]

the android emulator works only if I change the network to host only.

and when I try to connect to adb from Santoku machine it gives me:

> unable to connect to 192.56.103:5555 (IP of the android machine)

Comment: "host only" does what it says, so what's the question?

Comment: I can not connect to android machine adb from another linux machine!

Comment: >the android emulator works only if I change the network to host only.

That's probably the problem: the host-only interface is used by Genymotion to communicate with VirtualBox, it has nothing to do with the network of the virtual device, which is handled by VirtualBox DHCP by default, or your local network DHCP if you set the network mode to Bridged. In other word, 192.56.103 is on a different sub-network than the host-only interface.

In order to communicate, the virtual device and your Linux VM have to be on the same sub-network.

Comment: Let me explain with pictures:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the various networks. Let me explain with images.
The Genymotion virtual device has 2 network adapters: a host-only and a NAT or Bridged adapater.

Adapter 1:
[image]

Adapter 2:
[image]

The first adapter is used exclusively by Genymotion player to communicate with VirtualBox - the Android OS virtualization is handled by VirtualBox and Genymotion emulates the display via OpenGL translation through this interface. It should not be used by anything else but Genymotion.

The second adapter is the device network adapter: this is how the virtual device communicate with your local network to reach the internet. It is NAT by default which means that the device network is handled by VirtualBox DHCP. If you set the device network mode to Bridge, then the device network will be handled by your local network DHCP (as on the second screen).

Communication with the virtual device should be done via the same network as adapter 2. So, the solution is to set your Santoku VM network adapter in Bridge mode and use the same network interface than Genymotion VD adapter 2 (wlo1 in my case):

[image]